# Why does this simple code fail in firefox yet work in every other browser including opera and old IE versions

Tags: javascript, firefox, conditional-statements, undefined

```
function T(x){ return (x.textContent) ? function(y){ x.textContent = y; } : function(y){ x.innerText = y; }; }

T(nodeA)('string');
nodeText = T(nodeB);
nodeText('string');
```

If I change `(x.textContent)` to `(x.textContent !== undefined)` it works in firefox. Otherwise I get no errors but nothing happens. Inspecting with firebug shows that `T(node);` returns `function()`, which is just baffling to me.

I'm new to javascript but I'm thinking this could be a bug?? I think it can only be true or false, it should be true and return first function but it doesn't return either. Can someone say why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pHwCm/ --- it doesn't work in chrome. What is `nodeA`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nnA7Z/ --- but anyway it **does work** if I specify nodes manually

Comment: @zerkms It works in chrome for me. I was just giving examples of how I'm using the function; nodeA is a different node from nodeB.

Comment: @zerkms manually??? I mean node as any dom object that would have a  textContent property or an innerText property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work if the `textContent` for the given node is an empty string `''`, which evaluates to `false`.  That's why you should do `(typeof x.textContent !== 'undefined')` instead to ensure the existence of the property.

Comment: I'm not understanding your answer. If the condition evaluated to false why isn't the second function: `function(y){x.textContent;}` returned?

Comment: when I test in firebug console both `textContent` and `innerText` properties exist. So to my thinking whichever function gets returned, should work. Problem is neither gets returned.

Comment: Actually that's a good point regardless. I still don't understand why this is going wrong in firefox, but I should change it anyway or it could assign the wrong function because of an empty string. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Firefox doesn't have support for the non-standard `innerText` property.